# aus, bei, mit, nach, seit, (usw)

Tags: grammatical-case, mnemonic

> "aus, bei, mit, nach, seit, von, zu, gegenüber"

I vaguely remember this list of prepositions (I hope it's correct) which we had to learn by heart in my German class 30 years ago. But I don't remember what the list was for. Wasn't it something about the use with a specific *Fall*?

Comment: Maybe you meant “seit” instead of “zeit”?

Comment: @carsten - genau. Korrigiert...

Comment: Here's a link to a blog covering the word Nach. I encountered this conversation in my own pursuit of learning the German language. Scratches head... On Stack Exchange? Seriously?
Cool, I'll check that out. Anyway... Here ya go, hope its helpful.
http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/03/04/nach-meaning/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are prepositions requiring the dative. There is a mnemonic rhyme (dt.: Eselsbrücke) you can learn to keep them in mind:

> "Mit, nach, von, seit, aus, zu, bei
>
> verlangen stets Fall Nummer drei."

More such stuff is for instance [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Merkspr%C3%BCchen#Deutsch).

Examples:

> Er fuhr mit **dem** Bus. Nach **dem** Bus kam ein zweiter...

Answer (score 2):

> Aus, Bei, Mit, Nach, Seit, Von, Zu
>   Bring the dative case to you!

(Oh yeah, and *gegenüber*. But that doesn't rhyme or scan. Just remember that, kids!)

Can't remember much of German GCSE, apart from *Modellflugzeug* (model aeroplane, nice long strange word), my age, the rooms in my house and "What I have in my pencil case"  *(Ich habe einen Taschenrechner!)*

But I **do** know what to apply the dative case to. Whatever that is. I knew once.

Oh! Oh! I did have to give directions to Warwick Castle once! Got lots of use out of *"An der rechten Seite"* etc. Sadly didn't had a library, school or bus station to use as reference. And the chap wasn't very interested that *"Ich habe zwei Schwestern"* or *"Ich habe einen Taschenrechner"*....